# $\lim_\limits{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\arcsin(1-\{x\})\arccos(1-\{x\})}{\sqrt{2\{x\}}(1-\{x\})}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Find $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\arcsin(1-\{x\})\arccos(1-\{x\})}{\sqrt{2\{x\}}(1-\{x\})}$$ where $\{\cdot\}$ stands for the fractional part function, without using the L'Hopital Rule.
>
> Answer: $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Here's what I did:

Since $0<0^{+}<1\Rightarrow$ $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\arcsin(1-\{x\})\arccos(1-\{x\})}{\sqrt{2\{x\}}(1-\{x\})}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\arcsin(1-x)\arccos(1-x)}{\sqrt{2x}(1-x)}$$
This is of the form $\frac 00$. Also, $\lim_\limits{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\arcsin(1-x)}{1-x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Now we are left with $\lim_\limits{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\arccos (1-x)}{\sqrt{2x}}$.

This is the perfect moment to apply the LH rule but the question forbids it :(

Any hints on how to proceed further will be great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just nitpicking that the statement $0<0^+<1$ represents nothing. It's a bad notation. And there are no infinitesimals in real number system, and no two infinitesimally close real numbers.

Comment: @Mann I just used that statement to get $\{x\}=x$. Though that is bad notation, agreed.

Comment: You can say something like, Let 0<x<1. This is perfectly fine. You just approach the limit point 0 from within the neighborhood (0,1).

Comment: @Mann Alright, thanks. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $1-x=\cos\theta$ and we get the equivalent limit

$$\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\arccos(1-x)}{\sqrt{2x}} = \lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\arccos(\cos\theta)}{\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}} = \lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{|\theta|}{2\left|\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|} = 1$$

Comment: +1. Short and sweet :P

Answer (score 2):

Use
$$
\cos ^{ - 1} (1 - x) = \tan^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{{\sqrt {1 - (1 - x)^2 } }}{{1 - x}}} \right) = \tan^{ - 1} \left( {\sqrt x \frac{{\sqrt {2 - x} }}{{1 - x}}} \right)
$$
and write
$$
\frac{{\cos ^{ - 1} (1 - x)}}{{\sqrt {2x} }} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\frac{{\sqrt {2 - x} }}{{1 - x}}\frac{1}{{\sqrt x \dfrac{{\sqrt {2 - x} }}{{1 - x}}}}\tan^{ - 1} \left( {\sqrt x \frac{{\sqrt {2 - x} }}{{1 - x}}} \right).
$$
You can finish by noting that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{{\tan ^{ - 1} z}}{z} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to 0} \frac{w}{{\tan w}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to 0} \frac{w}{{\sin w}}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to 0} \cos w = 1.
$$

Comment: +1 Wow. Thanks. Never thought it would look this convoluted.